# Apache doesn't start at boot

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm on a VPS that sometimes OVH restarts. When this happens, apache soesn't start at boot so I need to start it manually everytime. I have already set the command systemctl enable httpd  but seems useless. How can I start apache at boot?

Comment: OVH? What distro?

Comment: I have CentOS 7

Comment: do you have a passphrase for your private key on a SSL vhost ?

Comment: Well, for every account on my VPS I have used a passphrase (and admin password have more than 200 character) but I don't use SSL certificate for my site...

Comment: I'm not a CentOS grey beard, but is the init script executable?

Answer (score 0):

Try:`chkconfig --level 23456 httpd on`.

Make sure that you don't have any errors in your apache configurations.

Comment: It says: Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service'.

Comment: @Gixone It prints "Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service" because using chkconfig is deprecated in your CentOS version.